# For a group $G$ and $a_1,a_2,a_3\in G$, if $a_1a_2a_3=e$, then does it follow that $a_2a_3a_1=e$ and that $a_3a_2a_1=e$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Question: Let $(G,\ast)$ be a group. If $a_1,a_2,a_3 \in G$ satisfies
$$a_1a_2a_3=e,$$
prove that
$$a_2a_3a_1=e.$$
Is it true that $a_3a_2a_1=e$?

My first thought:
$$a_1a_2a_3=e$$
$$a'_1a_1a_2a_3=a'_1e$$
$$ea_2a_3=a'_1e$$
$$a_2a_3=a'_1$$
$$a_2a_3a_1=a'_1a_1$$
$$a_2a_3a_1=e$$
For $a_3a_2a_1=e$, I think it is not true.
From the result,
$$a'_2a_2a_3a_1=a'_2e$$
$$ea_3a_1=a'_2e$$
$$a_3a_1=a'_2$$
$$a_3a_1a_2=a'_2a_2$$
$$a_3a_1a_2=e$$
But, $a_1a_2$ may not equal to $a_2a_1$.

However, a friend ask me that why the above proof "assume" $a'_1a_1=e$. The binary operation $\ast$ is not defined in the question. If I do the above proof, it seems I have assumed the binary operation $\ast$ is multiplication. Then I am in trouble now. How can I correct my mistakes?

Comment: Elements  in groups have inverses. You could have said "let $a_1'$ be the inverse of $a_1$". Also you could have written $a_1a_2a_3$ as $a_1*a_2*a_3$ etc., throughout. But why bother?

Comment: When you say $ab$, what you implicitly mean is $a*b$.  I thought that you just dropped the $*$ for convenience.

Comment: I find this quote vague "By the similar way, I can show that $a_3a_2a_1=e$ is not true."  How did you show this?  (It is not difficult, but I don't see how a "similar way" can show that $a_3a_2a_1=e$ may be wrong.)

Comment: Completing the previous comments: try to get a counterexample for non-abelian groups, of course, otherwise, $a_{3}a_{2}a_{1} = a_{1}a_{2}a_{3}$ ever

Comment: Also, avoid nondescriptive titles like "Abstract Algebra: Groups."  There are tons of threads that can use this title.

Comment: "However, a friend ask me that why the above proof "assume" a′1a1=e".  That is the *definition* of $a_1'$ being the multiplicative inverse.  It is the *definition* of a group that such an $a_1'$ exists and $a_1'a_1 = a_1a_1' = $. "The binary operation ∗ is not defined in the question."  It doesn't have to be.  We are told that $G$ is a group.  That *mean* by definition that a binary operation exists and that no matter *what* it is, for $a_1$ there *will* be an $a_1'$ so that $a_1'a_1 = a_1a_1' = e$.

Comment: "If I do the above proof, it seems I have assumed the binary operation ∗ is multiplication. "  No, it doesn't.  It only seems you have assumed an operation exists.  ANd that is valid.  It *does* exist.  You were told it does. "Then I am in trouble now."  No, you are not.  "How can I correct my mistakes?"  Well, you could stop discussing math with friends who aren't as intelligent as you are.  Or at least not assume they are right and you are wrong when they make a trivial objection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $a_1a_2a_3 = e$ then $a_1a_2a_3a_1=ea_1 = a_1$ and so $a_2a_3a_1 = a_1^{-1}a_1a_2a_3a_1 = a_1^{-1}a_1 = e$

So that is true.

If $a_3a_2a_1 = e = a_2a_3a_1$ then $a_3a_2 = a_3a_2a_1*a_1^{-1} = a_2a_3a_1a_1a_1^{-1} = a_2a_3$ and there is utterly no reason that should be true.

It's easy to come up with a counter example.  Let $G$ be a non-abelian group and let $a_2a_3 \ne a_3a_2$.  Let $a_1 = (a_2a_3)^{-1}$.  Then $a_1a_2a_3 = e$ and $a_2a_3a_1 = e$.  But $a_2a_3 \ne a_3a_2$ so $a_2a_3a_1 \ne a_3a_2a_1$.

(Note: this basically is paraphrasing and using the same reasoning of the "cancelation law".  $a = b \iff ac = bc$ for all $c$ in the group.)

Answer (score 1):

The assumption that $a_1a_2 = a_1 \ast a_2$ is fair. Writing without the operation is a standard way of more compactly notating these long products.

As for your proof, it looks good. Essentially, $a_1 a_2 a_3 = e$ implies that $a_2 a_3$ is a right-inverse of $a_1$, which must always be a (two-sided) inverse.

You also say "By the similar way, I can show that $a_3 a_2 a_1 = e$ is not true". This statement concerns me, because you can't really prove this in a similar way. It's something that may be true in specific cases, but will not be true in general. You'd need to formulate a counterexample in order to prove that $a_3 a_2 a_1 = e$ is not always true.

Comment: From the result,
$$a'_2a_2a_3a_1=a'_2e$$
$$ea_3a_1=a'_2e$$
$$a_3a_1=a'_2$$
$$a_3a_1a_2=a'_2a_2$$
$$a_3a_1a_2=e$$
Then, $a_1a_2$ may not equal to $a_2a_1$. So I thought it is false.

Comment: How do you know it isn't the case that $a_1 a_2 a_3 = e \implies a_1 a_2 = a_2 a_1$? It clearly doesn't, but you'd need a counterexample to prove it definitively.

Answer (score 1):

If $(G, *)$ is defined as a *group*, then for all $g \in G$, there should be a unique $g^{-1} \in G$ such that $g*g^{-1} = e$.

But we sometimes write $gg^{-1}$ by omitting the binary operation, which has the same meaning. Because of the same reason, in some books, for example it is said that "$G$ should be closed under **multiplication**" although the defined binary operation is not always multiplication.

For $a_3a_2a_1 = e$ case, I can say that  is not always true. For example, take 
$$Q_8 = \{i,j,k,e'\ |\ (e')^2 = e, i^2 = j^2 = k^2 = ijk = e'\}$$
Then $kji = e$ but $ijk = e' \ne e$.